# Using NFS with Ververica for artifact storage not working, throwing Error: No suitable artifact fetcher found for scheme file

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to setup Ververica community edition to use NFS for artifact storage using the following values.yaml

```
vvp:
  blobStorage:
    baseUri: file:///var/nfs/export
volumes:
  - name: nfs-volume
    nfs:
      server: "host.docker.internal"
      path: "/MOUNT_POINT"
volumeMounts:
  - name: nfs-volume
    mountPath: /var/nfs
```

When deploying the flink job, using job uri below:

```
jarUri: file:///var/nfs/artifacts/namespaces/default/flink-job.jar
```

I am able to see my artifacts in the Ververica UI, however when I try to deploy the flink job it fails with the following exception:

```
Error: No suitable artifact fetcher found for scheme file
```

Full error:

```
Some pod containers have been restarted unexpectedly. Init containers reported the following reasons: [Error: No suitable artifact fetcher found for scheme file]. Please check the Kubernetes pod logs if your application does not reach its desired state.
```

If I remove the "file://" from the jobURi to just the following the job containers keep restarting without giving error.

```
jarUri: /var/nfs/artifacts/namespaces/default/flink-job.jar
```

As a side note, I also added the following to the deployment.yaml, If I set the artifact to pull from an http endpoint it does save the checkpoints correctly in the NFS, so it seems that the only problem is loading artifacts from the nfs using file:// scheme.

```
  kubernetes:
    pods:
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-volume
          volume:
            name: my-volume
            nfs:
              path: /MOUNT_POINT
              server: host.docker.internal
          volumeMount:
            mountPath: /var/nfs
            name: my-volume
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ververica Platform does not currently support NFS drives for Universal Blob Storage.

However, you can emulate this behavior if using version >= 2.3.2 by mounting the NFS drive to your Flink pods as you did in the deployment spec for checkpoints. This works because 2.3.2 added support for self-contained and fetching local files. You can see more information in the documentation [here](https://docs.ververica.com/user_guide/application_operations/artifact_management/index.html#bundled-artifacts)

Comment: Upgrading to 2.3.2 fixed the issue!

Comment: @suh Hi! I am product manager at Ververica and would be interested to learn more about your adoption journey and the context in which you use Ververica Platform CE. If you have time for a quick call to share some feedback, let me know via konstantin(at)ververica(dot)com.